# Using The Facebook IOS SDK To Post To Friends Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios5, sdk

I am using the Facebook IOS SDK and I want to gain maximum exposure for an app I currently updating.

At the minute the app prompts the user to connect with facebook on the app load if the user is not already connected. If the user then connects I use the following code to send a Post to the users wall.

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/video-fx+/id530087007",@"link",
                               @"Video FX+ Live Video Editing",@"name",
                               @"Video FX+ is a fun, creative way to create stunning videos.",@"caption",
                               nil];
[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                      andParams:params
                  andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                    andDelegate:self];
```

Is this the best approach? Ideally I want the post to appear on the friends wall of the user who has signed in.

Would the above work or do I need to pull a list of the users friends and then loop through that list and post the message to each individual user?

Thanks

Comment: where is access_token? and you are posting on your own feeds.

Comment: This is using the IOS SDK the token is generated using the in-built methods. Just wondering if I post an update on my wall will it appear on other users news feeds?

Comment: nope not a good option, Do you want to send it to all of your friends?

Comment: Hi, yes I would like to send it to all of the users friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting to your own feed, will display that feed to all your online friends likely (sometime depends on facebook Most Recent/ Top story selected by your friends) so chances are they can miss it. 
On the other hand posting to all of your friends first by pulling all your friends (me/friends) and iterate over all friends and post the message is one by one is no recommended as person may have 5000 friends and posting 5000 wall post likely ban / report spam your application.

So, its better to post on your own wall.

Answer (score 1):

check this out

```
  NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/video-fx+/id530087007",@"link",
                                   @"Video FX+ Live Video Editing",@"name",
                                   @"Video FX+ is a fun, creative way to create stunning videos.",@"caption",
                                   nil];
    [self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed",friendFacebookID]
                          andParams:params
                      andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                        andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Thanks, I see that the example shows how to post to a friends wall. I think however I am going to stick to posting only to the users wall. I have tested it and my posts are appearing on friends walls.

Comment: @PiyushKashyap self.facebook when you declare and how to declare that . please tell me .